# TensorFlow : custom layer for-loop performance [TensorArray, map_fn]

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop, machine-learning, keras

Thank you very much for reading my question. I am quite new to tensorflow and I wrote this simple custom layer such that I can implement data dependent condition where a different set of variables can be selected and trained base on input.

```
class Custom_Layer1234(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=45, input_dim=45):
        super(Custom_Layer1234, self).__init__()
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()

        self.w_0 = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units,)),trainable=True)
        self.w_1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units,)),trainable=True)
        self.w_2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units,)),trainable=True)

        self.b_0 = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,)),trainable=True)
        self.b_1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,)),trainable=True)
        self.b_2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,)),trainable=True)

    @tf.function    
    def call(self, inputs):
        my_list = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=64, dynamic_size=False) //batch_size = 64
        
        i = 0 
        for x in inputs:
            This_diff = x[1]        
            x = tf.reshape(x,shape=(1,-1)) //if i dont reshape cannot tf.matmul  
    
            if This_diff > 0 :
                my_list = my_list.write(i, tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_0) + self.b_0))
            elif  This_diff < 0 :
                my_list = my_list.write(i, tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_1) + self.b_1))       
            else:
                my_list = my_list.write(i, tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_2) + self.b_2))
            i += 1
        
        return my_list.concat()
```

the code has no problem running fit, just that it is extremely slow, to a point that cpu training is even faster than gpu training, but still take a long time. Alternatively I tried :

```
class Custom_Layer1234(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=45, input_dim=45):
        .....

    def Mapping_this_Function(self, x):
        This_diff = x[1]        
        x = tf.reshape(x,shape=(1,-1))    
        if This_diff > 0 :
            return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_0) + self.b_0)
        elif  This_diff < 0 :
            return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_1) + self.b_1)      
        else:
            return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_2) + self.b_2)
    
    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs):  
        return tf.map_fn(self.Mapping_this_Function,inputs, parallel_iterations=64)
```

this can compile and fit also but `very strangely` accuracy becomes abnormally low value 1.6342e-04 comparing to usual 0.1-0.2 in first epoch and doesn't increase over time rather decreases overtime, is it that map_fn should not be implemented in custom layer.
in both cases I experimented with and without:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

Am I doing correctly for such 'for loop over batch-size tensor' condition, may you please point out a more efficient way that I missed out. I have very shallow understanding about how the codes run under the hood, but found out that cpu in general is better in doing sequential while gpu is better for parallel. I slice input tensor in smaller pieces and use this custom layer a couple of times, would it worth a try for me to even write custom operation in c++.

Many Thanks

Comment: If you set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` then GPU training won't work. Also, how slow is training and how fast do you expect? What data are you training with?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply ! my dataset is ~150000 in size and input shape is one dimension, using TensorArray approach with GPU, is 13 hours per epoch, with CPU is 4 hours for an epoch, i am hoping for something below an hour if that is possible, thank you

Comment: By one dimension do you mean each instance is a vector of length 45? So `inputs` has shape `(64, 45)` when batched? Then you compare to the second element `x[1]` to determine which weight to use?

Comment: hi, thank you very much for responding to my question ! yes what you said is correct. x[1] would be a 'float32' value, when looping through the batch ```inputs```, individually each x ```inputs[i]``` would be an array containing 45 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to vectorise everything like so:

```py
@tf.function
def call(self, inputs):
    gt = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(inputs[:, 1] > 0, tf.float32), -1)
    lt = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(inputs[:, 1] < 0, tf.float32), -1)
    eq = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(inputs[:, 1] == 0, tf.float32), -1)

    x0 = gt * tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_0) + self.b_0)
    x1 = lt * tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_1) + self.b_1)
    x2 = eq * tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w_2) + self.b_2)

    return x0 + x1 + x2
```

Since the three conditions are mutually exclusive, exactly one of {`gt[i]`, `lt[i]`, `eq[i]`} will be 1, for each `i`, and will contribute to the result. So gradient calculation should still occur as normal, and the result should be equivalent to what you have above.

Comment: hi Aaron, this is certainly from the deepest of my heart the type of answer im looking for ! n that Im so sure its way beyond my tensorflow knowledge even spending weeks i wouldnt come up with,  mind blowing! Thank you for selflessly sharing your knowledge !

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, could you please mark it as correct so that it will be put in the list of "answered" questions?

Comment: Abosultely ! was trying to rate answer as useful but my reputation is too low, didnt know about this 'accepted answer' feature. thank you very much man !